# Fitrar array PHP

Tags: php, array

Tenho um array PHP, conforme ilustrado abaixo. Sei que posso filtrar eles percorrendo-os (*foreach*, por exemplo) e vendo se um valor atende um determinado critério. Mas tem algum modo mais simples e rápido de fazer esse filtro?

```
<?php
$clientes = [
   ['id' => 1, 'nome' => 'Alefe', 'valor_autorizado' => 12159.99],
   ['id' => 2, 'nome' => 'Bete', 'valor_autorizado' => 35122.00],
   ['id' => 3, 'nome' => 'Guimel', 'valor_autorizado' => 86242.90]
   ['id' => 4, 'nome' => 'Dalete', 'valor_autorizado' => 2342.31]
];
```

Por exemplo, quero todos os clientes com valor autorizado superior a R$ 40.000,00.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim. Você pode usar a função `array_filter`. Com essa função você precisa passar um *array* e uma função de *callback* que será responsável por retornar *true* ou *false*. Nessa função você pode colocar sua condição, por exemplo:

```
<?php

$clientes = [
   ['id' => 1, 'nome' => 'Alefe', 'valor_autorizado' => 12159.99],
   ['id' => 2, 'nome' => 'Bete', 'valor_autorizado' => 35122.00],
   ['id' => 3, 'nome' => 'Guimel', 'valor_autorizado' => 86242.90],
   ['id' => 3, 'nome' => 'Juimel', 'valor_autorizado' => 86242.90],
   ['id' => 4, 'nome' => 'Dalete', 'valor_autorizado' => 2342.31]
];

/* Valor acima de 40.000 */
$clientes_filtrados = array_filter($clientes, function($arr) {
    return $arr["valor_autorizado"] >= 40000;
});

var_dump($clientes_filtrados);

/* Valor acima de 40.000 e que começa com a letra G */
$clientes_filtrados = array_filter($clientes, function($arr) {
    return $arr["valor_autorizado"] >= 40000 && preg_match("/^G/", $arr["nome"]);
});

var_dump($clientes_filtrados);
```

[**Demonstração no IdeOne**](https://ideone.com/oMxYNn)

Comment: Perfeito, é isso mesmo que preciso! Uma dúvida, posso aplicar mais de um filtro dentro da função?

Comment: ahhh foi mais rapido :'( .... hehehe :D +1

Comment: @Andrey Pode sim. Editei minha resposta e adicionei essa opção também.